# Proof that $a\mid b \land b\mid c \Rightarrow a\mid c $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to prove:

> $a\mid b \land b\mid c \Rightarrow a\mid c $

$a\mid b$ means that a divides b if there is an integer k, that $b=k\cdot a$

Please give me a hint on how to start, because I have no idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a | b$ and $b | c$, you have $b = ka$ and $c = jb$. Thus $c = (jk)a$. Hence $a | c$.

Comment: That's a bit more than "a hint on how to start", no?

Comment: Best hint would of been, "think about it", or "use math"

Comment: Maybe. Or maybe one could have written, "You know what $a\mid b$ means; now, what does $b\mid c$ mean? what does $a\mid c$ mean? Can you see some way to put the first two together to get the third?"

Comment: That is certainly an option.