# proof that if a|b and b|c then a|c

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Just wanted some feed back on the following proof

"if $a$ divides $b$ and $b$ divides $c$ then $a$ divides $c$"

I came up with this:

If $a|b$ then there exist some $x$ that $a * x = b$ and if $b|c$ there exist some integer $y$ that $b * y =c$ therefore if $a|c=z$ and $z=xy$ then $(a|b)(b|c)=a|c
)$.

Please let me know if I got this correct and I also wanted to know if there are more than one way to prove this statement, Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate: [Proof that $a\mid b \land b\mid c \Rightarrow a\mid c $](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/456372/201168). See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/538423/201168).

Answer (score 1):

$b=ka$ and $c=k'b$ implies $c=kk'a$ and thus $a\mid c$.

Comment: can you explain what ' on k'b represents, haven't learned that yet in my class.

Comment: $k$ and $k'$ are just simply non-zero integers.

Comment: It's just some variable. When two variables are related in usage or meaning, we often write them as __, __' to hi-light that fact, but it's e same as if we had used an entirely new symbol. Here, it highlights the fact that $k,k'$ are the numbers introduced by the definition of divides, as opposed to one of the numbers we start with in the problem. It's read "kay-prime"

Comment: @NgChungTak Does $k$ and $k'$ have to be non-zero integers? It seems the proof still works if they are zero, too.

Comment: @john that's OK for $k'=0, k\ne 0$ which yields $a|b \land b|0 \implies a|0$.  But for $k=0$, only $a|0 \land 0|0 \implies a|0$ is valid (though somehow redundant in some sense) which means $k=0 \implies k'=0$.  Special care will be needed for $a|0$, etc.