# If a|b and b|c , (how can I prove) ⇒ a|c?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I understand that if a|b, then amodb=0, thus a = q*b (remainder is zero) and b = q*c.
How can I prove using this that a|c?

Comment: $a = qb$ and $b = pc$ so $a = qpc$

Comment: just do it.......

Comment: This is absolutely a duplicate.  Anyone wanna help me search for it?  If nothing else, it's a no context question.

Comment: There is also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1727445/proof-that-if-ab-and-bc-then-ac) which is itself a duplicate.

Comment: $a\mid b$ implies $b\mod a=0$, not $a\mod b=0$.

Answer (score -2):

Note: From now, we will be assuming $j,k\neq 0.$

Since $a|b,$ we can say $b=ja$ for $j\in \mathbb{Z}.$ Similarly, $b|c$ so $c=bk$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}.$

Substituting for $b$ yields $c=ajk.$ Clearly, $jk\in \mathbb{Z}$ so, our assertion is true. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Anything wrong with my answer? Why the down vote?

Comment: why must j and k be positive?

Comment: Hmm thats true. But it is just a minor thing. The claim still holds for negative integers.

Comment: Yes, but it might be why you are getting downvoted. You should edit it.

Comment: @Prathmesh Answering PSQs is obviously against MSE rules, hence your two downvotes

Comment: Ah sorry I just actively began posting here yesterday :) I was unaware

Comment: @Prathmesh Thanks for the answer, solved my issue.

Answer (score -2):

By assumption, $na=b$ and $mb=c$ for some integers $m$ and $n$. Therefore $mna=c$ so that $c$ is an integer multiple of $a$ ( and of course $a|c$ by definition). $\blacksquare$

Comment: You knew this was/is a duplicate when you posted this answer.  Yet you answered anyway.  Do not answer posts that have already been asked and answered four times over, minimally.  It becomes just noise.  Answer questions needing answers, not those which have already been answered repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. @amWhy Really great attitude by the way, I searched, but I coudn't find anything with the title of this own thread.